# reverse event trigger in python script

Tags: python

I have a throw switch which triggers the relevant output from the script below when open but does nothing when it is closed. I would like it to do the opposite i.e. it triggers the relevant output when closed but not when open but having played around with the various parameters cannot get it to do what I want.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import smtplib
import time
import datetime

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# function for the door opening
def door_open():
    print datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

#initialise a previous input variable to 0 (assume button not pressed last)
prev_input = 0
while True:
  #take a reading
  input = GPIO.input(21)
  #if the last reading was low and this one high, print
  if ((not prev_input) and input):
    door_open()
  #update previous input
  prev_input = input
  #slight pause to debounce
  time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want it to trigger when the switch is flipped from opened to closed? Or do you want it to trigger while it remains closed?

Comment: @Dimitry - I want it to trigger when flipped from open to closed. It is a door switch and currently it's default state is open. When the door is opened the switch closes hence the function 'door_open' in the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting something like this after the check for `door_open()`:

```
if (prev_input and (not input)):
    door_closed()
```

You'll need to implement `door_closed()`, of course.

Comment: @Dimitri - Thanks Dimitri. That works. Time I started to learn some Python from first principles I think